How to map and highlight corresponding sentences in React, like DeepL?
I am building a React-based translation application, aiming for functionality similar to DeepL. The interface consists of two panels:

Left panel: Displays the original text.

Right panel: Displays the translated text.
I want to implement a feature where clicking on a sentence in the original text (left panel) highlights both that sentence and its corresponding translated sentence (right panel). Similarly, clicking on a sentence in the translated text should highlight both it and the corresponding original sentence.


Currently, I am trying to use contentEditable for the text in both panels, but I am running into significant issues:

Direct DOM manipulation: Since contentEditable operates directly on the DOM, it bypasses React's Virtual DOM, causing inconsistencies.

Re-render issues: When React re-renders the component, the DOM state managed by contentEditable is reset or overwritten, leading to errors or unexpected behavior.

Unstable interaction: Maintaining a stable state for highlighting and sentence mapping becomes difficult due to these issues.


Questions:

Is contentEditable a viable option for this use case, or should I consider alternatives for managing editable and interactive text in React?
How can I efficiently handle sentence-level mapping and highlighting in React while keeping the DOM and Virtual DOM in sync?
Are there any libraries or tools that can help implement this functionality, similar to how DeepL handles sentence interaction?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or recommendations for libraries that can simplify this process. Thank you!
function useObserver(editorRef: RefObject<HTMLElement>) {
  const [observer, setObserver] = useState<EditableObserver>()

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!editorRef.current) return

    console.log(
      "useObserver - Initializing EditableObserver:",
      editorRef.current
    )
    setObserver(new EditableObserver(editorRef.current))
  }, [editorRef])

  return observer
}


const Translations = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [isTranslating, setIsTranslating] = useState(false)
  const [beforeTranslationSentence, setBeforeTranslationSentence] = useState("")
  const [afterTranslationSentence, setAfterTranslationSentence] = useState("")
  const [targetLanguage, setTargetLanguage] = useState<LanguageFormat>(EN)
  const [originalLanguage, setOriginalLanguage] = useState<LanguageFormat>(JP)
  const [originalSentences, setOriginalSentences] = useState<Sentence[]>([])
  const [translatedSentences, setTranslatedSentences] = useState<Sentence[]>([])
  const [mappings, setMappings] = useState<Mapping[]>([])
  const [highlightedIndex, setHighlightedIndex] = useState<number | null>(null)
  const japaneseTextFieldRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null)
  const translatedTextFieldRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null)
  const editorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const isComposingRef = useRef(false)
  const observer = useObserver(editorRef)

  const handleClickTranslateButton = async (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    // Omission
  }

  const flushChanges = () => {
    if (!editorRef.current || !observer) return

    const el = editorRef.current
    if (observer.isUpdated()) {
      const updatedContent = Array.from(el.children).map(
        child => child.textContent || ""
      )
      observer.runWithoutObserver(() => {
        observer.rollback()
        setOriginalSentences(
          updatedContent.map((text, index) => ({
            ...originalSentences[index],
            text
          }))
        )
      })
    }
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (e: ReactKeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (!editorRef.current || !observer) return

    const el = editorRef.current

    // Enter Key Proccess
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (isComposingRef.current) return // Skip if in IME
      e.preventDefault() // Prevent default line breaks
      const currentPosition = getCurrentPosition(el)
      const prevContent = serialize(el)
      const content = insertTextByIndex(
        prevContent,
        "\n",
        currentPosition.position
      )
      const nextPosition = currentPosition.add(1) // Move to next line

      observer.runWithoutObserver(() => {
        syncUpdateContent(el, nextPosition, () => {
          setOriginalSentences(prev =>
            prev.map((s, i) => ({
              ...s,
              text: i === currentPosition.position ? content : s.text
            }))
          )
        })
      })
    }

    // Backspace Key Process
    else if (e.key === "Backspace") {
      if (isComposingRef.current) return // Skip if in IME
      e.preventDefault() // Prevent default deletion
      const currentPosition = getCurrentPosition(el)
      if (currentPosition.position === 0) return // Ignored if at the beginning

      const prevContent = serialize(el)
      const content = deleteTextByIndex(prevContent, currentPosition.position)

      observer.runWithoutObserver(() => {
        syncUpdateContent(el, currentPosition.add(-1), () => {
          setOriginalSentences(prev =>
            prev.map((s, i) => ({
              ...s,
              text: i === currentPosition.position - 1 ? content : s.text
            }))
          )
        })
      })
    }
  }

  const handleInput = () => {
    if (isComposingRef.current) return
    flushChanges()
  }

  const handleCompositionStart = () => {
    isComposingRef.current = true // Begin IME input
  }

  const handleCompositionEnd = () => {
    isComposingRef.current = false // Finish IME input
    flushChanges()
  }

  const handleHighlight = (index: number | null, isOriginal: boolean) => {
    if (index === null) {
      setHighlightedIndex(null)
      return
    }

    const mapping = mappings.find(m =>
      isOriginal ? m.originalIndex === index : m.translatedIndex === index
    )

    if (mapping) {
      const targetIndex = isOriginal
        ? mapping.translatedIndex
        : mapping.originalIndex
      setHighlightedIndex(targetIndex ?? null)
    } else {
      setHighlightedIndex(null)
    }
  }

  // Height adjustment of TextField
  const adjustTextFieldHeight = () => {
    if (japaneseTextFieldRef.current && translatedTextFieldRef.current) {
      // Browser automatically changes scroll position when height is changed while typing, so it remembers the scroll position and restores it later
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY
      const japaneseTextarea = japaneseTextFieldRef.current
      const translatedTextarea = translatedTextFieldRef.current
      japaneseTextarea.style.height = "auto"
      translatedTextarea.style.height = "auto"
      // Align the size to the highest TextField.
      const biggerHeight = Math.max(
        japaneseTextarea.scrollHeight,
        translatedTextarea.scrollHeight,
        MIN_TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT
      )
      japaneseTextarea.style.height = `${biggerHeight}px`
      translatedTextarea.style.height = `${biggerHeight}px`
      window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    adjustTextFieldHeight()
  }, [beforeTranslationSentence, afterTranslationSentence])

  return (
    <>
      <Container sx={{ mt: 4, p: 4 }}>
        <Paper sx={{ my: 4, p: 4 }}>
          <Grid container columns={16}>
            {/*Input*/}
            <Grid item xs={7}>
              {originalLanguage}
              {originalSentences.length > 0 ? (
                <Paper
                  elevation={3}
                  sx={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    border: "1px solid #e0e0e0",
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    boxShadow: "none"
                  }}
                >
                  <div
                    id="original-sentences"
                    ref={editorRef}
                    contentEditable
                    suppressContentEditableWarning
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                    onInput={handleInput}
                    onCompositionStart={handleCompositionStart}
                    onCompositionEnd={handleCompositionEnd}
                    onMouseUp={e => {
                      const selection = window.getSelection()
                      const range = selection?.getRangeAt(0)
                      const parent =
                        range?.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement

                      const paragraphIndex = parent
                        ? Array.from(e.currentTarget.children).indexOf(parent)
                        : -1 // Get the index of the parent element

                      if (paragraphIndex >= 0) {
                        setHighlightedIndex(paragraphIndex)
                      }
                    }}
                    style={{
                      minHeight: "300px",
                      padding: "8px",
                      lineHeight: "1.6",
                      borderRadius: "4px",
                      border: "1px solid transparent",
                      outline: "none",
                      cursor: "text",
                      whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"
                    }}
                  >
                    {originalSentences.map((sentence, index) => (
                      <div
                        key={index}
                        data-index={index}
                        onMouseEnter={() => setHighlightedIndex(index)}
                        onMouseLeave={() => setHighlightedIndex(null)}
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor:
                            highlightedIndex === index
                              ? "#fffa65"
                              : "transparent",
                          margin: "0",
                          padding: "4px 0",
                          minHeight: "30px"
                        }}
                      >
                        {sentence.text}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </Paper>
              ) : (
                <textarea
                  rows={10}
                  placeholder="Input text"
                  value={beforeTranslationSentence}
                  onChange={e => setBeforeTranslationSentence(e.target.value)}
                  style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    padding: "8px",
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    border: "1px solid #ccc",
                    lineHeight: "1.6"
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
              {isTranslating && <_Progress />}
              <_SubmitBtn
                variant="contained"
                colorScheme="green"
                onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent) =>
                  handleClickTranslateButton(e)
                }
              >
                <Box>
                  <Box>Translate</Box>
                  <_rightArrow />
                </Box>
              </_SubmitBtn>
            </Grid>
            {/*Output*/}
            <Grid item xs={7}>
              {targetLanguage}
              {translatedSentences.length > 0 ? (
                <Paper
                  elevation={0}
                  sx={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    border: "1px solid #e0e0e0",
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    boxShadow: "none"
                  }}
                >
                  <div
                    style={{
                      minHeight: "300px",
                      padding: "8px",
                      lineHeight: "1.6",
                      borderRadius: "4px",
                      border: "1px solid transparent",
                      outline: "none",
                      cursor: "text",
                      whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"
                    }}
                  >
                    {translatedSentences.map((sentence, index) => (
                      <div
                        key={index}
                        data-index={index}
                        onMouseEnter={() => handleHighlight(index, false)}
                        onMouseLeave={() => handleHighlight(null, false)}
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor:
                            highlightedIndex === index
                              ? "#fffa65"
                              : "transparent",
                          margin: "0",
                          padding: "4px 0",
                          minHeight: "30px",
                          lineHeight: "1.6"
                        }}
                      >
                        {sentence.text || (
                          <span style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>empty</span>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </Paper>
              ) : (
                <textarea
                  value={afterTranslationSentence}
                  onChange={e => setAfterTranslationSentence(e.target.value)}
                  readOnly
                  style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    padding: "8px",
                    fontSize: "16px",
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    border: "1px solid #ccc",
                    minHeight: "231px",
                    lineHeight: "1.6",
                    resize: "vertical"
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

